# Is it possible to bind an order by column?

Tags: php, oracle, php-7

I'm trying to allow the user to choose the order they want to sort results from a database in with php and oracle. 
I have a bind working in the where clause, but I can't make it work with the order by clause.
Is there a way to bind an order by statement?

I can't find anything in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php).

Sample Code:

```
<?php
$db = ...
$sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE val1 = :val1 ORDER BY :orderBy";

$id = oci_parse($db, $sql);

// this works
$val = "test";
if (oci_bind_by_name($id, ":val1", $val)) {
  echo 'bound where clause';
}
// this doesn't
$orderBy = "val1";
if (oci_bind_by_name($id, ":orderBy", $orderBy)) {
  echo 'bound order by clause';
}

?>
```

Comment: In PDO and mysqli there is not. I'm not sure about the `oci` driver. With the other two the way to do it is with a whitelist of known terms. e.g. `$valid_columns = array('column1', 'column2'); $order = in_array($orderBy, $valid_columns) ? $orderBy : 'Default_Column';`

Comment: Bind params are for values, rather that just parts of the SQL statement. This is not a PHP thing, it's a DB thing. The DB processes the SQL statement separately from the values used in the SQL statement, if possible.

Comment: You can specify a number to represent the positions of the columns to order by e.g `select col1, col2, col3 from t1 order by 1` or `order by 2`. It might be with trying to see if the binding handles this.

Comment: **The basic rule** The query that you issue to the prepare or parse in your case must be able to be compiled by the database engine. If columns are missing the database cannot compile and optimise the query. So the answer is NO

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to use bind variables to alter the `ORDER BY`:

```
<?php

$conn = oci_connect('hr', 'welcome', 'localhost/orclpdb');

$query = "select first_name, last_name
          from employees
          order by
              case :ob
                   when 'FIRST_NAME' then first_name
                   else last_name
              end";

$vs = "FIRST_NAME";

$s = oci_parse($conn, $query);
oci_bind_by_name($s, ":ob", $vs);
$r = oci_execute($s);

echo "<table border='1'>\n";
while (($row = oci_fetch_array($s, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) != false) {
    echo "<tr>\n";
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        echo "  <td>".($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES):"&nbsp;")."</td>\n";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No you can't.
Oracle SQL processing goes through an initial parse phase, then one or more bind and fetch phases (and the fetches can be partial or completed for the entire results set).

The execution plan is fixed at parse so that binding new variables does not change the execution plan. If the initial select were "SELECT NAME, DEPT, HIRE_DATE FROM EMP ORDER BY HIRE_DATE" or "SELECT NAME, DEPT, HIRE_DATE FROM EMP ORDER BY 3", the execution plan may choose to use an index on HIRE_DATE to obtain the rows in the requested order without requiring a sort.

If the statement were to become "SELECT NAME, DEPT, HIRE_DATE FROM EMP ORDER BY 2" that execution plan would return the results in an incorrect order. As such, that statement has to be parsed separately and the order in which the results are required determined before the bind phase is performed.